# Is there a software available that can make one game on server playable by multiple clients?

Tags: gaming, client-server

my sister has a cybercafe business which is typically have a server PC and clients PC. I want the multiple clients to access the game directly into the server, so I no longer install the games/online games in every clients' computer.

Anyway, I tried to test an online game playing it in two client at a time but it doesn't work.

So Is there a software capable of making one game playable by multiple clients?

Comment: There are solutions available for many games, but the solution is specific to each game.

Comment: [diskless system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskless_node) ?

Comment: You're looking at Cloud Gaming then

Answer (score 0):

Difficult, since if you try **remote desktop** type stuff.. it would **kill your server**. If you try to run off **shared drive** the environment may not be same (**registry**).

Why dont you look at software that allows you to do remote installs, I have no exp. with it but they discuss it [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/software/217039-ways-install-software-multiple-computers-same-time.html)?

edit: not specifically games but similar issue is being discussed [here](http://www.frihost.com/forums/vt-92919.html), though main motivation there is cost.

edit2:@LiuYan 刘研 seems to have a good idea in diskless systems. Have no experience with it but looks promising

Comment: Actually the server has a good spec. but though if it not a type which can't handle many users at least I am expecting 2-3 users playing the game at a time.  Any way the client's PC has also a CPU it is not just a monitor alone of course.